# How to use JavaScript & DOM on one html page to externally link to another html page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, external

So basically I have two html pages in the same folder.  One of them is the homepage, while the other is a page that basically is a form.  Once the person fills out the form and clicks the submit button, I would like to make it so that it automatically changes the homepages information with the information written out on the form using DOM.

What I have tried:

- Using an external & same JavaScript file for each HTML document, Firefox console said that the `id` is `null`
- Using global variables, did not work.

If I haven't worded this well enough or if you don't understand, please comment and tell me!

Here's an example of what I tried to do, didn't work because the `div` with id `type` is in a different HTML document.

```
function submitform(){
    var textbox = document.getElementsByName('name').item(0);
    value= textbox.value;
    window.alert(value);
    document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: You can't change anything on the page that you're not on. You can only remember what you want to change when you get there.

Comment: How about using cookies to store your information then showing them on your homepage.

Comment: @Derek or LocalStorage if IE is not to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Form page:

```
function submitform(){
    var textbox = document.getElementsByName('name')[0];
    value = textbox.value;
    localStorage["name"] = value;                      //save it in localStorage
}                                                      //for later use
```

Homepage:

```
function showStuff(){
    var value = localStorage["name"];                  //get the information back
    document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = value; //put it in
}
```

`localStorage` is supported on [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage). If you need to support < IE9, try [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).
**Try a DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/r4fXw/ or http://pastebin.com/SurbLhWZ

---

### Why none of your attempts works

1. Using an external & same JavaScript file for each HTML document, Firefox console said that the id is null

   Variables are not shared cross different webpages.
2. Using global variables, did not work.

   Same as #1.

Comment: Oh my freaking god that works!!! THANKS!  Any way to make it do it automatically?  like what i have now is a refresh button that is onclick = "showStuff()"  which is much less efficient.

Comment: @Alex - Try `window.onload = showStuff;` if you want it to run everytime the page is done loading.

Comment: @Alex - You can take a look at [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/r4fXw/) included in the answer, which is similar to what you are doing right now. ;) `showStuff()` is automatically executed every time the page loads.

Comment: im looking at the demo, not really sure what it means.  never seen any $ symbols in this.  i dont see where you wrote the window.onload=showstuff() too

Comment: @Alex - OK, I am using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) in my demo just for efficiency. (`$` is used in many libraries too) I can create a plain JavaScript one for you though.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/SurbLhWZ , and if you think my answer is helpful, you can upvote and accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables to one page from another requires some form of query with paramters, ie. `newpage.php?newdata='This came from the old page'`. You'll need to implement one of several options: as already mentioned, you could store the submitted data in cookies and then retrieve them on the subsequent page load, you could send the data back to the homepage using an actual submit query (see above) or you could use an AJAX routine to send the data to the home page without any type of submit action.